# How do to route to a new page from current existing login page in a "devise"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, devise

This is the devise sign in html form and I am not sure what resource_name is ? and how to route to the page that I want to go to after clicking on the "Sign in" button.

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>

<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
<div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
<% end -%>

<div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `application_controller.rb` , add this

```
  # after click sign in button - if resource is admin
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(Admin)
      admin_path    
    else
      super
    end    
  end
```

Or try this [redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

Hope this help